# How to use inputs in custom loss function with y_true and y_pred available

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, autoencoder

I have built an autoencoder in tensorflow which takes an input with missing values (-999.) which are then masked. The target/label is the clean version of the input with no missing values. The model is like this:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(input_size, 1))
model = Masking(mask_value=-999.)(inputs)
...CNN encoder and decoder...
model = CustomLossLayer(2.)([model, inputs])
model = Model(inputs, model)
model.compile(loss=None, optimizer='adam')
```

I would like to include a weight in my loss function such that the errors on the missing values are amplified. The idea is to try and encourage the model to get better at predicting the missing values.

The closest solution I have found uses these two classes:

```
class CustomLossClass(Loss):
    def __init__(self, weights):
        super().__init__()
        self.weights = weights

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):        
        return reduce_mean(square(multiply(subtract(y_true, y_pred), self.weights)))

class CustomLossLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, weight, name="custom_loss"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.weight = float(weight)

    def call(self, inputs):
        where_missing = equal(inputs[1], -999.)
        weights = where(where_missing, self.weight, 1.)
        self.add_loss(CustomLossClass(weights))
        return inputs[0]`
```

The functions reduce_mean, square, multiply, subtract, where and equal are all imported from the base tensorflow module.

When I run the code the error that is given is:

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred'
```

I do not understand how to pass the y_true and y_pred variables to the loss class. It was my understanding that if you define a loss as a layer (CustomLossLayer) and use add_loss, then it would automatically pass these to the CustomLossClass during training.

I have also tried using a loss() function wrapped in another function and including it in the model.compile(loss=...) but then it seemed impossible to pass the inputs for the current batch to the loss function to determine the locations of the missing data. Perhaps I need to do a custom training loop for this, but I'd like to avoid that.

Could anyone provide me with some advice or working code to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding y_true to the inputs of the model.

```
inputs = Input(shape=(input_size, 1))
inputs_flat = Flatten()(inputs)
ytrue = Input(shape=(input_size))
model = Masking(mask_value=-999.)(inputs)

... encoder and decoder layers ...

ypred = Flatten()(model)
ypred = AddWeightedMSE(5)([ytrue, ypred, inputs_flat])

model = Model(inputs=[inputs, ytrue], outputs=ypred)
model.compile(loss=None, optimizer='adam')

# add y_train to the inputs as a list, but not as second argument to fit()
model.fit([x_train, y_train], epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

using the following for the layer and loss classes:

```
class WeightedMSE(Loss):
    def __init__(self, weights):
        super().__init__()
        self.weights = weights

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        difference = subtract(y_true, y_pred)
        weighted = multiply(difference, self.weights)
        squared = square(weighted)
        mswe = reduce_mean(squared)
        return mswe

class AddWeightedMSE(Layer):
    def __init__(self, weight, name="custom_loss"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.weight = float(weight)

    def call(self, inputs):
        is_missing = equal(inputs[2], -999.)
        weights = where(is_missing, self.weight, 1.)
        self.add_loss(WeightedMSE(weights)(inputs[0], inputs[1]))
        return inputs[1]
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({'weight': self.weight})
        return config
```